# Publishing a geoprocessing service that imports modules besides arcpy?

Tags: python, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service

I'm trying to publish a geoprocessing service (10.2.1) that will be used to generate a PDF from a webmap using an MXD layout as a template.

The problem is that if I try to import any module besides `arcpy`, the publishing just runs forever until I kill it.

For example, I tried to `import os`, and it just hangs while it's publishing. When I remove `import os`, it publishes just fine. Same thing happens with any other module I try to import.

Any idea what's wrong here?

---

I found this thread that has the exact same problem, but there wasn't really a solution:

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/86236

---

I tried @KHibma's suggestion, and created a "script" with only `import os`, and no parameters at all. Of course it runs with no errors, but the same thing happens when I try to publish the geoprocessing tool. It just hangs until I decide to kill it.

I also did the same thing, but with only `import arcpy`, and it publishes fine.

Comment: If you use the "Analyze" button to analyze your service does it show any errors or warnings related to the modules?

Comment: Nope, it just hangs and does the Not Responding, but right when I remove the other imports and try again it works fine.

Comment: you're absolutely positive its the import doing it? ie. you have NOTHING in a script beside import os and you've tried to do it. I am aware of a couple issue that were fixed at some point in time, but dont recall just a simple import of system installed modules causing an issue.

Comment: @KHibma good suggestion. I updated my answer with the results.

Comment: I can't find a known issue on that (and cant reproduce it in a  more recent setup). Not sure what else to suggestion :(

Comment: I found that blog thread as well and it seemed like the solution was "I solved this by removing all references to my PYTHONPATH variables in Environment Variables-->System Variables (?) . The service is now created in 10 seconds." not sure if you want to try it but....

Comment: @ChrisR our server doesn't even have the PYTHONPATH variable. It just uses PATH. However, I did try adding PYTHONPATH, and it still doesn't work...

Comment: I found another [thread](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:A317cQweIcMJ:https://geonet.esri.com/thread/66569+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) not quite the same problem you are having but might not hurt to check out Kenndk's response, they reference PYTHONPATH but I know as you stated your server just uses PATH but maybe changing that variable to the path Kenndk mentions.